# Custom Post type plugin is using theme single.php and style.css

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am trying to make a plugin for the display of recipes on my website. I registered a custom post type which works. I even created a file called **template-single.php** for the elements I want to display in the post. The I call it with **get_template_part()** in **single-af_recipe.php**. For some reason this isn't working. My stylesheet for my plugin is also not working.

I tested this by putting **the_title()** in **h4** tags. In the theme they are **h1**. I also made the **h4** color red in **af_style.css**

Here are the files of my plugin:

I have a main file called recipe-maker.php where I include functions.php. Below I start from functions.php

**functions.php**

```
<?php

add_action('init', 'af_recipe_post_type');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'af_enqueue_scripts');
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'af_pluginprefix_install' );

//Enqueue styles
function af_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('af_style', plugins_url( 'recipe-maker/af_style.css', dirname(__FILE__) ) );
}

function af_pluginprefix_install() {
    // clear the permalinks after the post type has been registered
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

//Register custom post type for recipes
function af_recipe_post_type() {
    register_post_type('af_recipe', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Recipes'),
                'singular' => __('Recipe'),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'recipe' ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-aside',
        )                  
    );

}
```

**template-single.php**

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
   <div class="row">

            <div class="single-post-title">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <div class="single-post-date">
                <h4><?php the_date(); ?></h4>
                </div>    
            </div>  
    </div>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

</div>
```

**single-af_recipe.php**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">

    <?php while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/template-single.php'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try the free plugin "query monitor". it will help you to understand why the unexpected template file is used.

Comment: Is `template-single.php` in the theme, or your plugin?

Comment: @JacobPeattie in my plugin. But even without it and all the code just in single.php, the same happens.

Comment: try to remove the **.php** from the get_template_part code - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: @Feyt `get_template_part()` loads files from the site's *theme*, and the template hierarchy will not load templates from plugins.

Comment: @Michael thanks for pointing that out. Still didn't work though.

Comment: Here I uploaded it to GitHub if this will help - [https://github.com/FullNoob/Recipe-Maker](https://github.com/FullNoob/Recipe-Maker)